# Formal proof that for distinct $A_i$ and $B \subset \bigcup A_i$, $\sum P(B\cup A_i) = P(B)$

Tags: probability

What is a formal proof that for distinct $A_i$ and $\displaystyle B \subset \bigcup_{i\in I} A_i,$ $\sum_{i\in I} P(B\cap A_i) = P(B)?$

Is it just obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you mention holds if any pair of $A_i$ satisfies $A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset.$ If not, it is false in general. Also we need to assume that the family of $A_i$'s (that is, the set $I$) is finite or countable.

If  $A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset,$ for any $i\neq j,$ then the collection $B\cap A_i$ is a family of disjoints events.  Then, it follows from the third axiom of probability that

$$\sum_i P(B\cap A_i)= P(\bigcup_{i\in I} (B\cap A_i))=P(B),$$ where in the last equality we have used that $\displaystyle B\subset \bigcup_{i\in I} A_i.$

Answer (score 0):

use latex in your posts please. as to the question - the sets $B\cap A_i$ are, by definition of $A_i$ are disjoint and sum up to $B$. then you just apply definition of probability measure which is additive on disjoint, measurable sets.